# operation parameter must be str

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I need to insert with using only SQLAlchemy. Stack of technologies is only sqlite, sqlachemy for this.

`

```
# запись работника в таблицу users(ФИО, рандом др, роль(рандом из таблицы roles)
# вывод последних добавленных 5 работников
import json
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData
metadata = sa.MetaData()

roles = sa.Table('roles', metadata,
                 sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
                 sa.Column('name', sa.String(50)))

users = sa.Table('users', metadata,
                 sa.Column('id', sa.BIGINT, primary_key=True),
                 sa.Column('fio', sa.String(255)),
                 sa.Column('datar', sa.String(255)),
                 sa.Column('id_role', sa.Integer))

with open("C:\\Users\\kiril\\PycharmProjects\\testbotjob_project\\config.json", 'r',
          encoding='utf-8') as f:  # открыли файл
    options = json.load(f)  # загнали все из файла в переменную

db = options["data_base"]  # путь к бд

con = sqlite3.connect(db)
con.execute(roles.insert().values(name='Грузчик'))
con.close()

# with con:
#     con.execute("""
#             CREATE TABLE roles (
#                 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
#                 name VARCHAR(50)
#             );
#         """)
#     con.execute("""
#         CREATE TABLE users (
#             id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
#             fio VARCHAR(30),
#             datar DATE,
#             id_role INT,
#             FOREIGN KEY (id_role) REFERENCES roles (id)
#         );
#     """)
```

`

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kiril/PycharmProjects/testbotjob_project/database/db_con.py", line 26, in <module>
    con.execute(roles.insert().values(name='Грузчик'))
ValueError: operation parameter must be str
```

I was googled, but after 40 minutes i dont know.. Help please. Hope only for you.

Comment: The `execute` method from `sqlite3` isn't going to know what to do with the  object returned by `values`. You either need to associate your SQLAlchemy table objects with a database, or you need to get the SQL code associate with the SQLAlchemy object to pass to `con.execute`.

Comment: (I don't recall, but that might be as simple as something like `con.execute(str(roles.insert().values(name='...')))`.

Comment: I changed it to con.execute(str(replace.insert().values(name='Грузчик')))
But answer is: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.

Comment: In this task, it is forbidden to use raw SQL code for insert :(
I need to associate my SQLAlchemy table objects with a SQLite database, but i dont know how.. When i coding with SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL, code was worked without another associates.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html#inserting-rows-with-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb

answer: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html#inserting-rows-with-core

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///database.db", echo=True, future=True)
```

...

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
result = conn.execute(stmt)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: It seems that your answer won't help. My I ask you kindly how it solves the question?